# How do I setup this in Moq to give me null or an object?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, unit-of-work

I want to saw that I do not care what is in the Find clause. Just give me null.

Here is the test

```
[Fact]
public void VerifyIndexViewType()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockUserProvider = new Mock<IUserProvider>();
    mockUserProvider.Setup(x => x.GetUserId()).Returns("any-value-here");
    var mockUnitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    //how would I just return an object or null for example.. this doesnt work
   // mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.UserProfileDataRepository.Find(u => u.ApplicationUserId == "any value here")).Returns((IRepository<UserProfileData>)null);

    var controller = new ProfileController(mockUnitOfWork.Object, mockUserProvider.Object);

    // Act
    var result = controller.Update();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsType<ViewResult>(result);
}
```

For the following controller and action

```
public class ProfileController : BaseController
{
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IUserProvider _requestUserProvider;

    public ProfileController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
        IUserProvider requestUserProvider)
        : base(unitOfWork, requestUserProvider)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _requestUserProvider = requestUserProvider;
    }

    public IActionResult Update()
    {
        //this is easy
        string userId = _requestUserProvider.GetUserId();
        //how do I do the setup in moq for this? 
        IEnumerable<UserProfileData> userProfileQuestions = _unitOfWork.UserProfileDataRepository.Find(x => x.ApplicationUserId == userId);

        if (userProfileQuestions != null)
        {
            ProfileViewModel profileViewModel = new ProfileViewModel();
            profileViewModel.UserProfileData = userProfileQuestions.FirstOrDefault();
            return View(profileViewModel);
        }

        return View("Error", "Home");
    }
```

EDIT 1: MY IUnitOfWork and implementation of the method

```
  public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IRepository<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUserRepository { get; }
    IRepository<RefMedicalSpecialty> RefMedicalSpecialtyRepository { get; }
    IRepository<RefProgramDetailData> RefProgramDetailDataRepository { get; }
    IRepository<RefProgramProfileData> ProgramProfileDataRepository { get; }
    IRepository<UserProgram> UserProgramRepository { get; }
    IRepository<UserFeedback> UserFeedbackRepository { get; }
    IRepository<UserAction> UserActionRepository { get; }
    IRepository<UserProfileData> UserProfileDataRepository { get; }
    IRepository<RawCredential> RawCredentialRepository { get; }
    IRepository<RefProgramCharacteristic> RefProgramCharacteristicRepository { get; }
    IRepository<UserProgramRefProgramCharacteristic> UserProgramRefProgramCharacteristicRepository { get; }

    void Commit();
    void RejectChanges();
    void Dispose();
}

 public IRepository<UserProfileData> UserProfileDataRepository =>
      new Repository<UserProfileData>(_retContext);
```

Comment: Could you show `IUnitOfWork`?

Comment: Can we see the implementation of `UserProfileDataRepository`? That's the object you'll need to mock and pass to the repository since that has the method you want to set a test null return value for.

Comment: I am mocking the Find method right?  I just can't figure out the specific syntax to say 'Whenever the FIND method is used on this repository return … whatever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the Method Find as virtual

```
 public virtual YourType Find(Expression<Func<YourClass, bool>> yourfunc)
```

and the mock as:

```
mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.UserProfileDataRepository.Find(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<YourClass, bool>>>()).Returns(DefineYourReturn);
```

Comment: mockUnitOfWork.Setup(x => x.UserProfileDataRepository.Find(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<YourClass, bool>>>())).Returns(null); What does YourClass represent ? I think what you are saying is it will say for any time the Find method is used always return null (or whatever collection) right?

Comment: @punkouter, Yes, it always returns null or the collection that you define. "YourClass" means the type your are going to return. Example: your "Find", returns a collection of "UserProfileData", so can substitute "YourClass" to "UserProfileData".

Comment: @punkouter BTW, the virtual declaration is only necessary if your are not working with interfaces.

Comment: @punkouter If this answer has been answered your question, please define as answer